# elasticsearch (Python/Django) bulk indexing throws No Index error

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I am using `elasticsearch`'s python client and `elasticsearch-dsl` as well. I have created an index `IndexName` and I validated the existence of the index. I have a doc_type `DocumentModelIndex` associated with this `IndexName`.

```
def bulk_indexing():
        from app.models import DocumentModel
        DocumentModelIndex.init(index=settings.ES_INDEX)
        es = Elasticsearch()
        bulk(client=es,actions=(b.indexing() 
                for b in DocumentModel.objects.all().iterator()))
```

When I run the above code I get the following error: `ValidationException: No index`.

I tried Putting a document into that index using:
    curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/index_name/document_model_index/" -d "{\"source\":\"google\"}"
and this worked.

I am new to `elasticsearch` and am not able to figure this out. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

In the `DocumentModelIndex`DocType definition:
`class Meta: index = IndexName`.